# Select sum while selecting from multiple tables outputs incorrect result - Codeigniter 3.x model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this function in my model:

```
public function lanlordEarnYear()
{
$this->db->select('l.*, p.pName, u.uName, SUM(ci.amount) AS totAmntYear, SUM(pay.amount) AS landPayYear, t.unitId');
$this->db->from('landlords l, properties p, units u, cashIn ci, tenants t, landlord_payment pay');
$this->db->where('pay.landlordId=l.id AND ci.tenantId=t.id AND t.unitId=u.id AND u.propertyId=p.id AND p.landlordId=l.id AND STR_TO_DATE(ci.registeredTime, "%Y")=STR_TO_DATE(CURDATE(), "%Y")');
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->group_by('l.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

The associated tables are as follows:

cashIn table:

[image: cashIn table]

landlords table:

[image: landlords table]

Comment: If you're only getting a single sum and are expecting more rows, then perhaps you need a `$this->db->group_by('l.id, p.id, u.id');` ?  Strike that, I see you're passing them in, so no need to group on them.  I'd try adding some conditions to those joins!

Comment: If you wanted to show more tables, you only uploaded two images. I've added the two you have as inline tables, but they would be best as text anyway. Would you just do `SHOW CREATE TABLE x` for each of your tables, and paste the text? It is much easier for folks to work with.